# SharePoint 2013 how to set the system master page to default

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have created a custom master page through HTML, and successfully converted to SharePoint master page. I accidentally set the System Master page to this master page as well. I am trying to set the System Master page back to Seattle but I cannot through Master Pages page. (The input fields are missing, some controls are missing). How can I revert the System master page back to Seattle.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this powershell script:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://localhost/ 
$web.MasterUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/seattle.master" 
$web.Update()
```